# Update UITextView value from C++ class

Tags: c++, ios, listener

I need to implement a listener which update UITextView value, this value comes from c++ class.
My first idea is to mix c++ and objective-c but I don't know if I write this :

**Listener.h**

```
class Listener
{
  public:
    virtual void updateValue(NSString*) = 0;
}
```

**MyListener.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
class MyListener : public Listener
{
  private:
    UITextField *_text;
  public:
    MyListener(UITextField *);
    ~MyListener();
    virtual void updateValue(NSString*);
}
```

**MyListener.cpp**

```
MyListener::MyListener(UITextField *text) :
  _text(text)
{}

void MyListener::updateValue(NSString* value)
{
  _text.text = value;
}
```

Comment: you could do it, just you have to use the `Objective C++` for you classes, with `.h` and `.mm` files. if you can do it, you would try to convert the `.cpp` into `.mm` because working with pure `.cpp` files is a little bit harder case in `Objective C`. :)

Comment: Thanks for your notice. I just change compiler option to build sources as Objective-C++